# Kill processes using their name in php

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

i have the name of a long running process like `ffmpeg` (or more) and i want to kill it - or them - in php  and without using the `exec`

Is that possible ? Its just like `killall ffmpeg` linux command .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kill process in safe way using the posix function "posix_kill". 
Example:

```
// We assumes that 1223 PID is one ffmpeg process

posix_kill(1223, SIGHUP);  // This send a polite termination signal to the process

posix_kill(1223, SIGINT);  // This send a interrupt signal to the process

posix_kill(1223, SIGTERM); // This send the termination signal and tried to clean-up the process (Use it if SIGHUP and SIGINT fails)

posix_kill(1223, SIGKILL); // This send an unpolite signal to the kernel explaining that we want to kill the process ASAP and unconditionally and we don't care if we loss some data and the process is going to generate some memory leak (Use this as last option).
```

Now the problem is that you want to have the ffmpeg PID's, you can achieve that in a non-intrusive way reading the processes information from the "proc" filesystem.

Example that provides the process name:
/proc/1223/cmdline

In order to get the higher/maximum process number, you have to read the file /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max. Now you have to iterate across the process information in the "proc" filesystems until the pid_max is reached. You have have to check that process directory exists and that string returned from the /proc/xxxx/cmdline is contain the string "ffmpeg" or "libav" (Some linux distributions have renamed ffmpeg by libav or something like that).

Remember that in order to kill the ffmpeg processes the PHP script owner (Maybe Apache?) should be added to the same group that launch the ffmpeg processes.

Comment: Did you really read the answer? It explains that you can find the process by name iterating thought the /proc/xxxx/cmdline and then take the process name associated to the pid. It is way to know the process name and their PID.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can use linux commands via "exec" function, i don't know any other way. Check this out :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: exec have some security risks i can't use it for now.

Comment: Actually if you use it with filtered data it is so secure.

Comment: it want to keep it disabled so a hacker can't use it to run his scripts .
this is my boss will , not mine :D